Assets\Pinegenegrator.cs(26,80): error CS1503: Argument 4: cannot convert from 'UnityEngine.Quaternion' to 'UnityEngine.Transform'
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Pinegenegrator : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject pinePB;

    private float cd;
    public float timeDu;

    private void Awake()
    {
        cd = timeDu;
    }


    //instantiate

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        cd -= Time.deltaTime;
        if(cd <= 0)
        {
            Instantiate(pinePB, new Vector3(10, Random.Range(-1.2f, 2.1f)), 0, Quaternion.identity);
            cd = timeDu;
        }
    }
}

error code in unity:

Assets\Pinegenegrator.cs(26,80): error CS1503: Argument 4: cannot convert from 'UnityEngine.Quaternion' to 'UnityEngine.Transform'
Assets\Pinegenegrator.cs(26,77): error CS1503: Argument 3: cannot convert from 'int' to 'UnityEngine.Quaternion'


I tried changing many times and discovered an error in the sentence with the word "Quaternion.identity"your text
However, I still don't understand clearly and need everyone's help`

TKS FOR HELP


Can I replace it with anything?

Write this:
        Instantiate(pinePB, new Vector3(10, Random.Range(-1.2f, 2.1f), 0), Quaternion.identity);

No Instantiate method declaration can get an integer as a parameter, I think you just put the ')' symbol in the wrong place and didn't notice. However all the declarations of the Instantiate method you can find in this Unity doc: Unity Object.Instantiate

I tried again and it came up with another error code: "Assets\Pinegenegrator.cs(27,76): error CS1503: Argument 3: cannot convert from 'UnityEngine.Quaternion' to 'float'"

Hello @MinhTiếnThái , I'm sure you didn't copy and paste the line of code that I provided. The error is easy to understand and fix. So, I think at first you need to learn the c# programming because if you are not able to find out the reason for this error you do not have the fundamental knowledge. There are a lot of free tutorials on the internet, so I suggest you start with them. I'm sorry that I can't help you, I'm not a tutor.
P.S. Copy and paste the line instead of yours.
